# error when try to join two columns Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm new in Spring Boot. I've a simple project to do, but I'm getting an error that I'm not able to fix.

This is my User class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")

@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id_user")

public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    private @Id @GeneratedValue int id_user;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Note.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "un_fk", referencedColumnName = "id_user")
    private List<Note> notes;

    public User() {}

    public User(int id_user) {
        this.id_user = id_user;
    }

    public User(int id_user, String name, String surname, List<Note> notes) {
        this.id_user = id_user;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.notes = notes;
    }

    /*getters and setters*/
```

And this is my Note class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "note")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id_note")

public class Note implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id_note;
    private String content;
    private String title;
    
    private User user;

    public Note(){}

    public Note(Long id, String content, String title,User user ){
        this.id_note = id;
        this.content = content;
        this.title = title;
        this.user = user ;
    }
    /*getters and setters*/
```

This is my DTO:

```
public class JoinDto {

    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String title;

    public JoinDto(String name, String surname, String title) {
        super();
        this.title = title;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }
```

This is my repository:

```
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Integer>{
    
    @Query("SELECT new com.example.Crud1.dto.JoinDto(u.name, u.surname, n.title) FROM User u JOIN u.notes n")
    public List<JoinDto> getJoin();

}
```

It compile, but when I try to call from postman I get :

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'notes1_.un_fk' in 'on clause'
```

I really don't know what is the problem. I spent few days tring to fix it but I'm unable.

**----------UPDATE---------**
Found the error, it was @JoinColumn(name =...) wrong.

This are my tables note and user:

```
+---------+---------+-------+---------+
| id_note | content | title | id_user |
+---------+---------+-------+---------+
|       1 | nota1   | nota1 |       1 |
|       2 | nota2   | nota2 |       1 |
|       3 | nota3   | nota3 |       1 |
|       4 | nota4   | nota4 |       2 |
|       5 | nota5   | nota5 |       2 |
|       6 | nota6   | nota6 |       2 |
+---------+---------+-------+---------+

+---------+-------+---------+
| id_user | name  | surname |
+---------+-------+---------+
|       1 | user1 | user1   |
|       2 | user2 | user2   |
|       3 | user3 | user3   |
+---------+-------+---------+
```

but now it only return this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "user1",
        "surname": "user1",
        "title": "nota1"
    },
    {
        "name": "user2",
        "surname": "user2",
        "title": "nota2"
    },
    {
        "name": "user3",
        "surname": "user3",
        "title": "nota3"
    }
]
```

I think it must return notes from 1 to 6. Whats the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some errors in your HQL query, this should be ok:

```
    public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Integer>{
    
    @Query("SELECT new com.example.Crud1.dto.JoinDto(u.name, u.surname, n.title) FROM User u JOIN Note n on n.user= u")
    public List<JoinDto> getJoin();
}
```

Also I recommend you to  add a @ManyToOne annotation on field user in Note class

```
@ManyToOne
private User user;
```

Comment: Ok, now it work only if I do `...FROM User u JOIN Note n on n = u")` but if i print SQL it does `note1_.id_note=user0_.id_user`

Comment: It works, just added `(targetEntity = User.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` at the annotation. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

1. The `u.notes` is not an entity, it's just a field in User entity. You should replace it with Note
2. You miss the **ON** clause after the **JOIN** clause.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I found the error, but now I have another problem. I've updated the question. Hope you will help me, bye.

Comment: It looks like it's joining with `id_note` and `id_user`.

You should add `@JoinColumn(name = "id_user")` to `private User user`. Or add an `id_user` to Note class and join by that field.

Comment: if i print SQL it compare id_note to id_user, I added the annotation but nothing changed